# How much voltage will i generate from this DC motor?

Tags: voltage, motor, generator, speed, rpm

http://www.moog.com/literature/MCG/moc23series.pdf

i am using the C23-L33 model.

if i rotated the motor at the rated speed of 3000RPM, how much voltage will i generate?

can I please know the exact steps of finding the answer out using the datasheet above?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be read directly off the table on page 194.

[image]